# Maven Ant task SCP - Auth Fail

Tags: maven, ant

we are used to use a maven ant task to send our artifact to our servers, but now this is not working anymore... I don't know what changed, when maven runs the task, we get this exception

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (scp-to-remote) on project quipark: An Ant BuildException has occured: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<scp trust="true" password="password" localFile="path_to_jar" remoteToFile="admin@192.168.3.240:/Users/admin/Public/dir" verbose="true"></scp>... @ 4:204 in /Users/admin/sviluppo/workspace/app/target/antrun/build-main.xml
```

It's not working also if we use the keyhole option and not the password. It's strange because we can ssh into the server with the same credentials with no problem

This is the POM part of the plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scp-to-remote</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <scp localFile="${project.basedir}/target/app.jar"
                                    remoteToFile="${remoteToFile}"
                                    verbose="true" password="${password}" trust="true">
                                </scp>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- libraries for scp impl -->
                <!-- antrun doesn't use os's scp -->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

`${remoteToFile}` is taken from my Maven settings and it's like admin@192.168.3.240:/Users/admin/Public/dir

This is the full stack trace of the exception

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (scp-to-remote) on project quipark: An Ant BuildException has occured: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<scp trust="true" password="password" localFile="path_to_jar" remoteToFile="admin@192.168.3.240:/Users/admin/Public/dir" verbose="true"></scp>... @ 4:202 in /Users/mario/GoogleDrive/sviluppo/workspace/quipark/target/antrun/build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (scp-to-remote) on project quipark: An Ant BuildException has occured: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
around Ant part ...<scp trust="true" password="password" localFile="path_to_jar" remoteToFile="admin@192.168.3.240:/Users/admin/Public/dir" verbose="true"></scp>... @ 4:202 in /Users/mario/GoogleDrive/sviluppo/workspace/quipark/target/antrun/build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
around Ant part ...<scp trust="true" password="password" localFile="path_to_jar" remoteToFile="admin@192.168.3.240:/Users/admin/Public/dir" verbose="true"></scp>... @ 4:202 in /Users/mario/GoogleDrive/sviluppo/workspace/quipark/target/antrun/build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: /Users/mario/GoogleDrive/sviluppo/workspace/quipark/target/antrun/build-main.xml:4: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp.execute(Scp.java:187)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:313)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHBase.openSession(SSHBase.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp.upload(Scp.java:249)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp.execute(Scp.java:176)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are missing an username="xxxxx" from your scp task

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the username is in the `remoteToFile` var, as for SCP specs, i will edit the question

Comment: would you be able to comment the command that you are using? and also could you turn on verbose output and post the results please?

Comment: have you tried key based authorisation? to rule out a version conflict

Comment: yes i did, i used the keyfile option to link to my .ssh/id_rsa and i have the IP in my known_host file but same result...